# SKScene touchesBegan only registering first touch when presented from SpriteView

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, spriteview

I'm using SwiftUI and trying to implement touchesBegan method from an SKScene object so that touches on the left half of a SpriteView create a green box, and touches on the right half create a red box. This works to a point, but cannot handle multiple simultaneous touches. It seems to work fine when not run from within a SwiftUI SpriteView (i.e. when presented by an SKView of a UIViewController).
Here's my GameScene.swift...

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let colour: SKColor
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if location.x > self.frame.midX {
                print("right")
                colour = .red
            }
            else {
                print("left")
                colour = .green
            }
            let box = SKSpriteNode(color: colour, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
            box.position = location
            box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
            addChild(box)
        }
    }
}
```

...and my ContentView.swift...

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 350)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 500, height: 350)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `isUserInteractionEnabled` true?

Comment: yep. tapping on both left AND right sides simultaneously, creates only one box though; either left OR right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. Add 'view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true' to GameScene.didMove(to view:)

Need to know:

1. UIView has property '[isMultipleTouchEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled)'.
2. SKView is inherited from UIView.
3. The default value of this property is false.